# jQuery script runs on jsFiddle but not locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use a script I found to create a dependent drop-down list on my webpage. Unfortunately. While the code works properly on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwv18zo1/), it doesn't work at all on my end.

```js
var $select1 = ('#select1'),
  $select2 = ('#select2'),
  $options = $select2.find('option');

$select1.on('change', function() {
  $select2.html($options.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1">
      <option value="1">Fruit</option>
      <option value="2">Animal</option>
      <option value="3">Bird</option>
      <option value="4">Car</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
      <option value="1">Banana</option>
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="1">Orange</option>
      <option value="2">Wolf</option>
      <option value="2">Fox</option>
      <option value="2">Bear</option>
      <option value="3">Eagle</option>
      <option value="3">Hawk</option>
      <option value="4">BWM
        <option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm pretty new to HTML and JS, so please forgive me if I made any super obvious errors!

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Exactly what isn't working?  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: So you've given us a working example, but you've given us nothing to reproduce the issue on your end. How are we supposed to help?

Comment: Why do you call jQuery twice?

Comment: @QuentinVeron also, 2 different versions

Comment: You have two versions of jQuery, remove one and use a document.ready handler. I'd suggest familiarising yourself with http://learn.jquery.com. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 4):

I've been there before.

Try wrapping your code with the following:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //  Your code here
});
```

CodePen automatically does this.

The error here is that your JavaScript is running before your HTML has loaded, and so your `#select1` and `#select2` don't actually exist yet. You're looking for something that hasn't loaded.

**Update**

> The comment section has made some good points, but my answer is still addressing the *primary* reason your code has not been working. Here is the full snippet which will run in your browser

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>=
      <script>
         $(function() {
                    var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
         $select2 = $( '#select2' ),
          $options = $select2.find( 'option' );

         $select1.on( 'change', function() {
         $select2.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
         } ).trigger( 'change' );
         });


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <select name="select1" id="select1">
         <option value="1">Fruit</option>
         <option value="2">Animal</option>
         <option value="3">Bird</option>
         <option value="4">Car</option>
      </select>
      <select name="select2" id="select2">
         <option value="1">Banana</option>
         <option value="1">Apple</option>
         <option value="1">Orange</option>
         <option value="2">Wolf</option>
         <option value="2">Fox</option>
         <option value="2">Bear</option>
         <option value="3">Eagle</option>
         <option value="3">Hawk</option>
         <option value="4">BWM
         <option>
      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```